# What fast-xml-parser options preserve namespace and attributes when parsing and generating XML documents?

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

What [fast-xml-parser](https://naturalintelligence.github.io/fast-xml-parser/) options should I use in order to parse an input XML document to JSON and then write the identical XML document, preserving all namespace and attribute names and values?

Comment: have you figured out how?

Comment: No.  The documentation is insufficient.

Answer (score 7):

Since you want to preseve the attributes and namespace then `ignoreAttributes` and `ignoreNameSpace` should be set to false. Attribute prefix should be the same while parsing from XML to JS object and back to XML. Here is the complete example;

```
const xmlInput = `<any_name a="abc">
        <ns:person>
            <name1>Jack 1</name1 >
            <name2>35</name2>
        </ns:person>
    </any_name>`;

const options = {
    attributeNamePrefix : "@_",
    //attrNodeName: false,
    //textNodeName : "#text",
    ignoreAttributes : false,
    ignoreNameSpace: false,
};

const jsonOptions = {
    attributeNamePrefix : "@_",
    //attrNodeName: false,
    //textNodeName : "#text",
    ignoreAttributes : false,
    ignoreNameSpace: false,
    //format: true,
    //indentBy: "  ",
    //supressEmptyNode: false,
};

const json  = x2jParser.parse(xmlInput, options);
const parserJson = new j2xParser(jsonOptions);
const xmlOutput  = parserJson.parse(json, jsonOptions);
```

Input XML

```
<any_name a="abc">
    <ns:person>
        <name1>Jack 1</name1 >
        <name2>35</name2>
    </ns:person>
</any_name>
```

Output XML

```
<any_name a="abc">
  <ns:person>
    <name1>Jack 1</name1>
    <name2>35</name2>
  </ns:person>
</any_name>
```